# Term by term integration over a finite interval

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analysis, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am reading The Riemann zeta function by H.M. Edwards , $1974$, pg. $52-53$. Here the author denotes by $\rho$ the non trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function

He proves that the following series in $\rho$ converges uniformly in any disc $|s|\leq K$ when the terms $\rho$ and $1-\rho$ are paired $$\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{s-\rho}$$
For this he observes $$\left|\frac{1}{s-\rho}+\frac{1}{s-(1-\rho)}\right|=\left|\left[\frac{1}{\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)-\left(\rho-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right]+\left[\frac{1}{\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\rho-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right]\right| $$ which gives $$ \left|\frac{1}{s-\rho}+\frac{1}{s-(1-\rho)}\right|=\left|\frac{2\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\rho-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\right|$$
Now we have $$\left|\frac{2\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\left(s-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\rho-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\right|\leq \frac{C}{\left|\rho-\frac{1}{2}\right|^2}$$
**for all sufficiently large $\rho$ once $K$ is fixed** and because $\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{|\rho-\frac{1}{2}|^2}$ converges.

**Question: How do we have the last inequality for all sufficiently large $\rho$? How does it ensure the uniform convergence?**

Can someone please clear this doubt. Thank you.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry I could not follow. So we have an upper bound for the tail of the sum. How does it ensure uniform convergence?

Comment: Wait a second. I only now realize that $\rho$ was not intended to be an integer variable. Scratch all that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes $\rho$ is a complex number with real part between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Is it known that $\sum_\rho|\rho-\dfrac12|^{-2}$ converges? When I didn't read carefully, and mistakenly assumed $\rho$ to be an integer variable, the convergence was obvious. If the convergence of that sum is known for some other reason, then an argument like Weierstrass M-test should still work.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes that's okay. But I need an estimate valid for all $\rho$. Please see the answer below. But I am not able to understand why the second maximum exist or why $C_K$ should exist.

Answer (score 1):

When $|s|\le K$, we have $|s-\frac12|\le K+\frac12$. By the properties of $\rho$, we know that when $\Im(\rho)>\sqrt2(K+\frac12)$, there is $|\rho-\frac12|>\sqrt2(K+\frac12)$, so $|\rho-\frac12|>\sqrt2|s-\frac12|$. Consequently, we have
$$
\left|{2\left(s-\frac12\right)\over\left(s-\frac12\right)^2-\left(\rho-\frac12\right)^2}\right|\le{2K+1\over|\rho-\frac12|^2-|s-\frac12|^2}<{4K+2\over|\rho-\frac12|^2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. But how do we know that $\Im (\rho)$ is large enough? We have the first $\Im (\rho)$ at $\Im(\rho)\approx 14.1$. Then do we have similar inequality to the above inequality for small $\rho$?

Comment: Please prove an inequality valid for all non trivial zeros of Riemann zeta, $\rho$

Comment: As long as you can find a constant valid for large $\Im(\rho)$, you can automatically deduce that replacing $4K+2$ by a larger number will make the inequality work for all $\rho$.

Comment: By large, I mean that there exists $T>0$ such that when $\Im(\rho)>T$, we have $|\rho-\frac12|>\sqrt2(K+\frac12)$, which is certainly possible because there are $\zeta(s)$ has infinitely many nontrivial zeros.

Comment: I thank you for your guidance. Please show that how can we automatically deduce that replacing $4K+2$ by a larger number which will make the inequality work for all $\rho$. Please include this in your answer.

Comment: I will accept your answer for this help.

Comment: @Delta I just updated the answer. Please let me know if there are any other confusions.

Comment: I have one confusion. Will $C_K$ always exist? Can we have a nice representation of $C_K$?

Comment: I mean what is the upper bound for $\max_{0<\Im(\rho)\le\sqrt2(K+\frac12)}\max_{|s|\le K}\left|{2\left(s-\frac12\right)\over\left(s-\frac12\right)^2-\left(\rho-\frac12\right)^2}\right|$?

Comment: @Delta It is not important to give an exact expression for $C_K$. All we need to know is that it must exist, which follows from the fact that $K$ is finite.

Comment: But what happens when $s=\rho$? We have something unbounded then.

Comment: @Delta I read the your question again, and I just realize that all you need is to ensure the inequality will hold when $\rho$ is large, so we don't even need to bother $C_K$.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. But I need an inequality for all $\rho$.

Comment: @Delta Why? didn't you just say that $s=\rho$ will basically make the expression unbounded?

Comment: Yes I said. That's what I am asking. I am not able to understand that why these maximums exist?

Comment: @Delta The maximum exists when $K$ is fixed and $\rho$ lie far away from the range $|s|\le K$, which is basically what I am saying in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Why does the maximum exist? And should it lie in the set?

Comment: You edited the answer? Was your answer not valid for all $\rho$?

Comment: Yes, it is impossible to find a universal bound for all $\rho$ because setting $s=\rho$ will basically violate it.